# multivalued attributes in database of transaction

Tags: php, mysql, rdbms, database

I want to make software for one of local store. I am making table of transaction which have attributes

```
tran_id, name ,mob_no, date_of_sale, date_of_payment(multivalued),product(multi),quantity(multi),total_amount,unpaid
```

as buyer can pay in installments date_of_payment is mulivalued.
Is there any other better way for this? How to implement multivalued attribute in mysql?

Comment: what do you mean by *multivalued*?

Comment: multiple values separated by comma

Answer (score 1):

"multivalued" fields as you call them break First Normal Form (1NF). You need a 1-m table for this. Read up at http://web.archive.org/web/20110606025027/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html and http://www.databasedev.co.uk/database_normalization_process.html and they will begin to show you how to start designing a database.

Comment: yes, thank you , but then i have to create separate table for every transaction. There will be many transactions per day? Will it be good to create table associated with each transaction?

Comment: Sheesh, have you actually read what I pointed you to in that short time? I think not and the statement you just made would prove that. Do you think that all the store systems in use today have a separate table per transaction? If you are going to design such a system then you really do need to have a basic understanding of computer science. Please read the pages that I have supplied links to and there you will find some answers. To create a scalable and maintainable application I would suggest a few years at college might also help.

Comment: Thank you , But i m unable to find solution. What I said above actually what i  got from your article. I am expecting solution here. Not reference to theoretical articles. I can also point people to various articles instead of solution..

Comment: One of those links gives a perfect example of a 1-m table. You need to read the articles carefully. Do you think that programming and database design is something that can be learned in 10 minutes? I went to college and studied for years. I have pointed you to articles that tell you how to do it and they give excellent examples. I have given you the name of the type of tables. You really only need to read and understand.